# Is it possible to make this rounding effect with pure CSS?

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to make rounding like the dark area on the image below with pure CSS?

[image]

Comment: css border-radius http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_border-radius.asp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Absolutely.  Just create a DIV, and attach a class with rules like these:

```
.rounded_box {
    width: 90px;
    height: 60px;
    border-top-left-radius: 11px 30px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 11px 30px;
    background-color: #333333;
}

<div class="rounded_box"></div>
```

Depending upon the browser support you're looking for, you may need to add some additional vendor-specific prefixes for the border-radius lines.  Such as:

```
-webkit-border-top-left-radius: 11px 30px;
-webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 11px 30px;
-moz-border-radius-topleft: 11px 30px;
-moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 11px 30px;
```

Comment: Your code in a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/375Hv/).

Answer (score -2):

yes http://www.css3.info/preview/rounded-border/ is a great tutorial.

Comment: Please don't do link only questions, but instead add the information to your answer.

Comment: sry will do that next time ;-)

Answer (score -2):

Border radius is definitely the answer. Check out this handy little site which generates the code for you;

http://border-radius.com

Also note that it is not supported in IE 6, 7 or 8